# Add Datagrid Autofilter to the Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit, controltemplate, wpf-style

I am using the [Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition Datagrid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home) and I would like to have some autofilter option on the columns. The paid version (which is about 1000 dollars) includes this functionality, but my project doesn't justify this amount of money.

So I found this great [Autofilter Extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering) for the original WPF `Datagrid`, but it's incompatible with the Xceed (A.K.A. *Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition*) Datagrid.

As far as I understand it the Autofilter is just a style that sits on top of the Datagrid's Column Header. I tried to do the same on Xceed's Datagrid accessing the `ColumnManagerCell` but it didn't work, I think I am just missing something small. I tried:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}" >
    <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}, ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}" />
 </Style>
```

under the `Resources`, and I also tried to use the `<Setter Property="Template"...` too, and it didn't work. `ColumnManagerCell` appears to be Xceeds "equivalent" to the WPF Datagrid `ColumnHeaderStyle`.

The code that works with the original Datagrid is:

```
<DataGrid ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey 
       TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}, 
       ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}"
```

As the extension's website points out.

I am also thinking about doing something like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="FilterTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}">
            <SomeControlInHere>
                <SomeControlInHere.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}" >
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource {ComponentResourceKey TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type filter:DataGridHeaderFilterControl}, ResourceId=DataGridHeaderFilterControlStyle}}" />
                    </Style>
                </SomeControlInHere.Style>
            </SomeControlInHere>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:ColumnManagerCell}">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FilterTemplate}"/>
        </Style>
```

But am I not sure what to target and how it will work in the end.

Does anyone knows how to place the [Autofilter Extension Style](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering) on the [Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition Datagrid](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home), and make the 2 work together?